# wx.MediaCtrl plays audio only

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, media-player

I am trying to play a video using wx.MediaCtrl. When I run my code, the video does not play, only the audio does. I have tried with different videos and file formats but the problem persists.

Here is my code:

```
import wx
import wx.media

class Video(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)
        self.Media = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_QUICKTIME)
        videoPath = "/Users/sherylhsu/Documents/sadf.mp4"
        self.Media.Load(videoPath)
        self.Media.Play()


app = wx.App(redirect=False)
mainFrame = wx.Frame(None, title="Temp")

video = Video(mainFrame, wx.ID_ANY)

mainFrame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing the `mainFrame` so the video doesn't appear.
The simplest way to get this to work is to make `Video` the frame:

```
import wx
import wx.media

class Video(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id)
        self.Media = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        videoPath = "/Users/sherylhsu/Documents/sadf.mp4"
        self.Media.Load(videoPath)
        self.Media.Play()
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(redirect=False)
video = Video(None, wx.ID_ANY)
app.MainLoop()
```

or keeping your exisiting code, simply move the `Show` into the `Video` class.

```
import wx
import wx.media

class Video(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)
        self.Media = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        videoPath = "/Users/sherylhsu/Documents/sadf.mp4"
        self.Media.Load(videoPath)
        self.Media.Play()
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(redirect=False)
mainFrame = wx.Frame(None, title="Temp")
video = Video(mainFrame, wx.ID_ANY)
app.MainLoop()
```

Note: if you don't give `MediaCtrl` a `backend`, it will pick the most appropriate.